# rounded view's corners android, NOT round background

Tags: android

I know how to give round borders using XML in Android. I thought it would be cool to make the radius of one corner of my textView excessively large. The problem is, the text keep spilling out. Can I make my textview have a TRULY round corner? (Not just the background). If this was CSS this would be so easy. I am new to Android.

So in terms of CSS, I want to set my overflow to hidden so to speak.

Please help me.

Comment: In terms of CSS, the TextView cannot be given rounded corners such that the text will be clipped/wrapped. All Views are bounding boxes. Do you have an issue where setting the background isn't sufficient for your needs? (describe this, if so)

Comment: Yes, I do. I want to create a round cornered scrollable view but it won't work if the texts come spilling out the corners.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine why using a shape drawable as the background  (of a ScrollView for example) wouldn't work; perhaps a picture will help others understand your issue with it.

Comment: great idea! I will upload a picture shortly after two hours or so.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. All Views are rectangular and fit in bounding boxes.

The best way to achieve rounded corners is the way you mention; using a shape drawable with corner radius set as the background to your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Like ataulm said, all Views are rectangular.

Create a shape drawable allows you to create a background with rounded corners. You'd have to use padding to make sure the text doesn't clip in certain areas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"/>

    <padding android:left="4dp"
         android:top="4dp"
         android:right="4dp"
         android:bottom="4dp"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
             android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: Padding is not what I am looking for. Hmm... Is there no workaround for this? some "underhanded" tricks I can employ?